# C# Localization per institution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I've been playing arround with resource files on a proof of concept. The idea is I can use use localization (.resx) files to localize form titles for a given institution. I realize that these files are typically used for localization text per culture. And that's where my question comes from. I don't feel my proof of concept is the best answer.

What I'm trying to do is use dataannotation on the model (MVC) to drive the form field titles. These titles would then be different based on a user's home institution.

I'm I using localization incorrectly and if so what are some other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I support driving this from a database. There is an old but still very relevant article by Michèle Leroux Bustamante at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx which goes into detail about how to do this. I have used this technique with great success on several projects.

It talks about ASP.NET 2 but its simple code and will work fine in an MVC site. You can even provide a simple UI to let admins update the resources if you feel so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be a case where database driven localization would be most appropriate? If you have text values dependent on a certain entity type or property? Would be easy enough to query for the correct "translation"

You can still use the DataAnotations you would just have to implement some custom resource manager which reads from the database.